# Partial ordered can be extended to total orders

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, well-orders

I am studying Halmos' *Naïve Set Theory*, and in Section 17, *Well Ordering*, he mentions the following exercise:

> Prove that if $R$ is a partial order in a set $X$, then there exists a total order $S$ in $X$ such that $R\subset S$; in other words, every partial order can be extended to a total order without enlarging the domain.

**Question:** For any set $X$, isn't $X\times X$ a total order on it? And $X\times X$ definitely contains $R$.

(I know I must be doing a blunder here since this is definitely not so trivial, as I had a quick look on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_extension#Order-extension_principle) for this.)

Comment: Well, if you have $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ then you must have $a=b$.

Comment: @lulu Yes, and $X\times X$ satisfies that, doesn't it?

Comment: But perhaps your partial order actually has $a<b$, not $a≤b$.

Comment: E.g., if $X = \{1, 2\}$, then $X \times X = \{(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)\}$, and we have both $(1, 2)$ and $(2, 1)$ in $X \times X$, but $1 \neq 2$.

Comment: @Hayden I guess the partial order you are considering (for which you write $1\ne 2$) is this: $\{(1,1), (1,2), (2,2)\}$. If so, then isn't that contained inside the Cartesian product?

Comment: @lulu Sorry, I still fail to see that. I hope my above example (in reply to Hayden) highlights what I must be missing from my understanding.

Comment: @Atom In the definition of antisymmetric (if $x \leq y$ and $y \leq x$, then $x = y$), the use of equality "$x = y$" is literal equality, not necessarily anything to do with the original partial order under consideration. $1$ and $2$ are unequal in the literal sense, so antistymmetry fails.

Comment: Perhaps you don't understand what a partial order is.  If our partial order has $a<b$ then this precludes $a=b$.  In a partial order two comparable elements must satisfy exactly one of $a<b, a=b, b<a$.  In a total order, any two elements are comparable.

Comment: @Hayden and lulu I now understood! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $X\times X$ is generally not a total order, or even a partial order on $X$. If “order” means “strict order”, then it fails irreflexivity and asymmetry (provided $X$ is nonempty), and if it means “non-strict order” then it fails antisymmetry (provided $X$ has more than one element).

Comment: Well, if $X$ is a singleton...

Comment: @Asaf I had addressed that corner case… but I modified my first sentence to be technically correct.

Comment: "The best kind of correct."